# 3.5 harm and greater harm

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Does anyone know why Harm deals 10 damage per caster level (max 150) and Greater Harm "only" 1d12 per caster level (max 20d12) ?

Even at 20th level Harm (150 damage) is more efficient than Greater Harm (130 damage on average).

Is there an error in the books, like Harm should deal 1d10 per caster level ?

Comment: @Hey I Can Chan Heroes of Horror

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no typo. The difference is that *[harm](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/harm.htm)* is a touch spell and *harm, greater* has a range of Close. It's not “greater” in the amount of damage it does, but in the range at which you can do it. The average damage done by *greater harm* when a cleric gains access to it (level 13) is ~85 at a range of 55 feet, at which point *harm* does 130 damage at melee range. They're complementary rather than *greater* superseding the original.

(Whether *greater harm* is a **good** complementary spell to *harm* is an entirely different subject.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, hadn't noticed the range increment :/